# How are sockets used for connections/streaming between application NOT over a network?

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming, lan

I have heard that sockets are used for all sorts of streaming between applications to send and receive data.

I have always thought and even read from articles that aim to give a "general sense" that sockets are used to create connections **over networks**.

However recently I saw that sockets are also used for local streaming/connections between apps which are not over a network.

My question;

- How are sockets used for connections/streaming NOT over a network between apps?

Comment: 'localhost' as server address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the applications are on the same machine then you can use the localhost or loopback address `127.0.0.1` as the IP address of the socket and any `port number > 1024` in both applications and then they can communicate over this connection .

Comment: I see! Are there alternatives to sockets for local apps? Thank you btw!

Comment: If you mean by local apps , applications running on the same machine then yes there are other ways to do it . It is called inter-process communication , for example : message passing , shared memory , Pipes in linux .

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want to use the socket approach and on linux, AF_UNIX is better than inet socket as they avoid some level of inet specific tasks like routing/adding-removing ip and transport headers, etc